# Usage of "estimate" as a noun

Tags: prepositions, nouns, paraphrasing

> Morgan Stanley, the best-performing stock this year among the five
> largest Wall Street banks, reported profit that beat **estimates on**
> a smaller drop in fixed-income trading revenue than analysts
> projected.
>
> Second-quarter net income rose to $1.94 billion, or 94 cents a share,
> from $980 million, or 41 cents, a year earlier, the New York-based
> company said today in a statement. Excluding an accounting adjustment
> tied to the firm’s own debt and a tax benefit, profit was 60 cents a
> share, **topping the 56-cent average estimate** of 24 analysts
> surveyed by Bloomberg.
>
> -- [Source](http://www.garp.org/risk-news-and-resources/risk-headlines/story.aspx?newsId=114602)

I've always run across "estimate **of** something" rather than "estimate **on** something". Does **on** here mean **based on**? Any other alternative prepositions could be used here?

And can I say "greater than the averaged 56-cent estimate" or "greater than the averaged estimate at 56-cent" in place of that part in bold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *estimate **of X*** means that the estimated value = X.

In your first sentence, ***on*** heads a preposition phrase which modifies *beat*. It means that the smaller-than-projected drop was the cause of profits beating the before-the-fact estimate.

You first paraphrase is accurate: the average estimate was $0.56, and profit, at $0.60 was greater than that. Your second, however, is not: *X was greater than Y at Z* is understood to mean that X=Z, not Y=Z.

Comment: I see. Z could be regarded as a subject complement by default, not a postpositional attributive. In the original example, could '56-cent' and 'average' swap positions?

Comment: @Zhanlong Yes: "topping the average 56-cent estimate" would not be misunderstood. But the author's way is better, because it is the *average estimate* which is 56 cents, not just the *estimate*

Comment: That particular usage of 'on' is new to me; I checked dictionaries bu couldn't find any related explanations. Is this usage restricted to any verbs or nouns?

Comment: @Zhanlongzheng It's typically used with achievement verbs -*win*, *lose*, *succeed*, *score*- and marks actions that bring about the change of state. It's very frequent in competitive situations, particularly athletics. "In the World Cup final, Germany beat Argentina on a beautiful goal by Mario Götze".

Answer (score 0):

The reference is to estimates **of** profits. That is, profits for Morgan Stanley were estimated at 56 cents a share, but today's "actuals"  (actual [ly reported result] s) of 60 cents a share (adjusted) beat that number.

Another way of saying it is 56 cents a share was Wall Streets "profit estimate" for Morgan Stanley.

In this construction, estimate is the noun and profit is a noun being used as an adjective.